# Returning false on empty input only works on one input, not both

Tags: jquery, validation, input, each

I am trying to check for one or both fields being empty before submitting using jQuery. If any inputs are empty, it's supposed to alert the user, else go to the ajax function. If I fill out the username field, it doesn't look at the password field. However, if I leave the username field blank, the correct dialog shows and it does not execute the ajax script. Am I using the .each() function wrong?

The html:

```
    <div id="dialog_success" title="Success">
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id="dialog_error" title="Error">
    <p>If you see this text, check your jQuery.</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="form-heading">Create New User</h2>
    <form id="insert_user_form" method="post" action="create_user.php" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="container">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username_input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" autofocus>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
            <button id="create_user_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The jQuery and part of the ajax:

```
$('#insert_user_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(':input').each(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $('#dialog_error').dialog("open");
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').css({'background': 'red', 'opacity': '0.7'});
            $('#dialog_error p').text("Please fill out all fields.");
            return false;
        }
        else {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                //Begin the ajax
```

I also tried:

```
if($(this).length === 0)
```

but that still did not work.

Comment: Seems excessive making ajax request for each input. You should probably re think this and make one request after validation of all input

Comment: I see what you mean. I wasn't thinking of where my brackets were going. I only want one ajax call. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned, you should make the AJAX call after checking all inputs. One simple way to do this is with a variable acting as a flag.

```
$('#insert_user_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isempty = false;
    $(':input:not(button)').each(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $('#dialog_error').dialog("open");
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').css({'background': 'red', 'opacity': '0.7'});
            $('#dialog_error p').text("Please fill out all fields.");

            isempty = true;
        }
    });
    if(!isempty){
        //Do your ajax
        // ...
```

That way, the variable `isempty` will be false if all inputs are filled out, and true if at least one isn't.

Also, `$(':input')` will also capture the `button` you have, so you can exclude it with the `:not` selector.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that about $(':input'). That worked!